# Flask-Compress module in google app engine not compressing response body

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, compression

I have a flask REST API service which will run in Google App Engine standard environment. I am using flask-compress module to compress the response.

When I am running the API service locally using PyCharm I am getting a response size of 1.35 KB for a particular API, but same API is resulting 14.5 KB response size while REST API service is hosted on Google App Engine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `Accept-Encoding` header is stripped from the incoming request by Google App Engine https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/request-response-headers

Comment: Can you please post this as an actual answer?